# User-defined function for catalog_apply does not return las with newly computed additional las attributes

Tags: lidr

I am trying to compute the actual incidence angles.
The following is the code that I used based on the example in the [lidR book](https://jean-romain.github.io/lidRbook/engine2.html#engine-user-function-generic)

Code:

```r
ang_calc = function(cluster, traj)
{
  las = readLAS(cluster)
  if (is.empty(las))return(NULL)
  las <- lastraj(las, traj, use.fun = TRUE)
  print(names(las@data))
  las <- lasangles(las, traj = c("xtr", "ytr", "ztr") )
  print(names(las@data))
  return(las)
}

output <- catalog_apply(lasc, ang_calc, traj)
```

The `print` commands confirm that the additional attributes are being added after each function. However, the final point cloud that is written on disk has none of the additional attributes. There was the following warning:

```
1: In regularize.values(x, y, ties, missing(ties), na.rm = na.rm) :
  collapsing to unique 'x' values
```

Just to test, I only read the cluster in the function and returned it without doing any thing. There was no warning and there was no difference in the files written on disk in both the cases.

Comment: You example is not reproducible. We don't know what is `lastraj()` or `lasangles()`. We don't have any data to reproduce. My guess is that you missed the function `add_lasattribute()`. Also, the warning likely to come from your code, there is nothing is `lidR` that is called `regularize.values()`

Comment: Also fix `catalog_apply(lasc, ang_calc, traj = traj)`

Comment: Hello, thanks for your reply! I will test if a basic add_lasattributes() works and perhaps answer this post if possible.